# Creating custom Iterator Java?

Tags: java, iterator

I'm a bit confused about how to implement a custom iterator for a class in Java. I'm required to essentially make an ArrayList without using the inbuilt libraries already available to me. I understand the basics of creating the class but I'm having trouble understanding how to get the Iterator to fit into all of this. I have the following:

I have created a generic class that implements the iterable interface as such it looks something like this:

```
public class MyArrayList<T> implements Iterable<T> {
```

I've then got to create a class called MyIterator which according to the wording of the document is a stand alone class. This seems fairly straight forward I make a new class called MyIterator and have it implement the iterator interface so it looks something like this:

```
public class MyIterator<T> implements Iterator<T>{
```

My confusion lies in the following. The document says that the Iterator needs to be in it's own class, but how then do I access the data members in "MyArrayList" to fully implement hasNext() and next() for example. As the data members in the underlying array are private (as they should be) I don't see how an external class can fully implement these methods. Am I misunderstanding what is required? By separate class is it still a part of the "MyArrayList" class but defined differently?

I hope that helps, as I said I think I understand what is required of me I just am not exactly sure where my Iterator fits into all of this.

Comment: `MyArrayList#iterator()` returns `new MyIterator(this)` or somehow passes a reference to itself & thereby gives access to the data

Comment: So is MyIterator part of the MyArrayList class or does it normally go in it's own, this is where I'm confused, I don't quite know "where" the Iterator goes, if that makes any sense. I know what the iterator() method is supposed to do but I don't know where I should add the code for my custom iterator so it can create an instance of it and call return it when I need it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

While the iterator has to be a separate class <sup>*</sup>, that class will probably have some relation to your `Iterable` class.

It's often a nested/inner class, precisely because it needs to access the values of the class (and that's what pretty much what inner classes are made for).

Granted, if the `Iterable` is a `List` you could implement an `Iterator` without any "internal" access at all, but you usually still want to get access to the internals for things like checking the `modCount` (to throw a `ConcurrentModificationException` when the `Iterable` is structurally modified while you iterate over it ... and to *prevent* that exception if you modify it via the `Iterator` itself).

<sup>* you *could* implement it with your `Iterable` instance itself, but that would break the contract as soon as the user uses two iterators at the same time.</sup>

Comment: So essentially I want to have a set up similar to the following:

    public class MyArrayList<T> implements Iterable<T> {
    
    public class MyIterator<T> implements Iterator<T> {
        
    }    
}
EDIT: Sorry I can't work out how to get code formatting working in comments.

Comment: @gRnt Exactly - iterator implementation can / should be a private class though since no-one needs to see the class. PS: put code in ` to get it formatted in text. http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting

Comment: Thankyou I think I was confusing "it's own class" with not being a nested class!

Answer (score 1):

You have to declare your own methods `hasNext()`, `next()`, `remove()`. It has to know how to iterate over your own class, how to go to next element and how to check whether next element exists.